# Zoom trigger effect in interactive 360video?

Tags: javascript

I have a 360 video that is interactive with pop up questions that are time based in the video. I want to tigger questions with specific frames, like if you zoom in and reach a specific frame in the video when zoomed in and then trigger a "hidden" question that dont show up in the video if you dont do that.

Can this be done in javaScript??  Have done some searching but cant find any specific information on it.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, it can be done in Javascript. You should supply some code showing where you're up to if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Zoom appends html inside the element it is assigned to, so that element has to be able to accept html.

```
// Example:
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.photo').zoom({url: 'photo-big.jpg'});
});

// Using Colorbox with Zoom
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.photo').zoom({
    url: 'photo-big.jpg', 
    callback: function(){
      $(this).colorbox({href: this.src});
    }
  });
});
```

To use zoom with img elements,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img')
    .wrap('<span style="display:inline-block"></span>')
    .css('display', 'block')
    .parent()
    .zoom();
});
```